# tkinter listbox.get(all the lists)?

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I was trying to get all elements listed in the list box. But it is dropping error messages. What I tried was:

```
def getValues():
    values = lb.get()
    return values
```

Comment: `lb.get(0,'end')` doesnt work?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked, thanks @Delrius Euphoria. That was assigning the first and last elements. The first was 0 and the last was the end of the list(END),

```
def getValues():
    values = lb.get(0, END)
    return values
```